# VBA Code for sorting data based on result of If Then statement in one column and Cell Color in another

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to have my macro sort my data based on the result of an IFERROR function in column A and the cell color in column B.

In column A, the IFERROR is performing a VLOOKUP on another workbook to check for matching values. Column A is highlighted Red by default, along with a bunch of other previously highlighted cells in the master workbook.

So basically, this is what I'm trying to make happen:

If column A passes IFERROR function AND is highlighted Red AND column B has No Fill, then select the entire row. I would like this to check the entire workbook.

Please forgive me if I am not making much sense, I'm having a difficult time putting this into words.

Comment: Have you tried any code for this?

Comment: Hardly. I do not even know where to begin.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: `code`
 Range("A:AH").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    If Range("A:A").Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0) And Range("B:B").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("A:A") IFERROR = False Then
    `code`

Comment: That's what I have, but the syntax is wrong, I know that. The IFERROR portion is what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Since each row has to be evaluated individually, you are going to have each two cell combination.

```
For i = 2 to lastrow
            If Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0) And Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Range("A" & i)) Then 

    'do your code if all are true

    end if
Next i
```

Comment: I think you have a couple of typos - `& lastrow` should probably be `& i`, and `IsErrorRange(...)` is (I assume) meant to be `IsError(Range(...))`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

`

```
Range("A2:AH2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISERROR(A2)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=ISNUMBER($A2)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False`
```